# Defining parallel sequences of jobs in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my `gitlab-ci.yml` file, I have defined 3 stages, and the 2nd and 3rd stages have 3 jobs each, resulting in the following structure:

[image: My current setup in GitLab]

The 1st and 2nd stage works as I intended, however, for the 3rd stage what I'd actually like to have is something like this (the image is a mockup of course), i.e. "parallel sequences" of jobs if you will:

[image: Mockup of the setup I'd like to achieve]

That is, I want *"deploy-b"* to start if *"build-b"* is done, and not waiting for the other build tasks to complete.

Is that possible with GitLab pipelines? (Apart from the obvious solution of defining just 2 stages, the second being "Build-and-Deploy", where I just "merge" the `script` steps of the current *build-** and *deploy-** jobs.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This [feature](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/08/22/gitlab-12-2-released/#directed-acyclic-graphs-dag-for-gitlab-pipelines) was added in the new GitLab release (**v12.2**)

Comment: This link is not working anymore. Is this supposed to take at this link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/directed_acyclic_graph/?

Comment: I'm glad this is possible. Is there an example of this working? @BhargavSangani

Comment: Did you read the link I put? Is it matching your use case?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible by design, a next stage only start if the previous one is done for GitLab version<12.2.